# R script - Calculate total cost for different groups based on cost criteria of another column?

Tags: r, dataset, data-analysis

I can't figure out how to calculate the cost of each Diet (D1-D4) based on Weight where cost for each diet is:

> D1: 2,2 * 10^-5 dollar / Weight
>
> D2: 2,8 * 10^-5 dollar / Weight
>
> D3: 3 * 10^-5 dollar / Weight
>
> D4: 3,2 * 10^-5 dollar / Weight

Do i need to create new columns for the costs or can it be applied in some sort of formula right away? Or some sort sort of when_case? I'm new to R so still learning the syntax

```
rawSourceData
Weight  Days Chicken  Diet Group NewDiet
42       0       1     1    G1     D1
51       2       1     1    G1     D1  
59       4       1     1    G1     D1     
64       6       1     1    G1     D1     
76       8       1     1    G1     D1     
93      10       1     1    G1     D1     
106     12       1     1    G1     D1     
125     14       1     1    G1     D1     
149     16       1     1    G1     D1     
171     18       1     1    G1     D1     
# ... with 568 more rows
```

I'd like to plot in as I did when calculating weight of Chickens at day 21 under each diet as below.

```
rawSourceData %>% group_by(Chicken) %>% filter(max(Days) >= 21) %>% ggplot( aes(x=Days, y=Weight, color=NewDiet, group=Chicken)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_grid(.~NewDiet)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, could give an example? do you want to create a new column in your table?

Comment: @bretauv 

I have 50 chickens divided into 4 groups, G1 to G4. 20 chickens in G1, 10 in G2 and so forth until 50 are divided among the groups. My goal is find out which of the four different diets, D1 to D4, that will yield the most weight of Chicken. In other words, which feed is the most efficient.

In my post above, D1 to D4 have various cost as you can see from the formula. The chickens are measured for every alternative day as you can see per the output of the df, until reached 21 days. 

So I want to find away to calculate which Diet is the best in terms of cost and plot it.

Comment: @bretauv 

But you see, I don't know how to write this syntax, and if i need to add new columns of cost and how to write the mathematic formula. Chickens that don't have measures up to 21 days are considered dead, hence should not be included.

Comment: hi, @AlexanderBerg, can you please have a look at my answer and let me know if that's what you were looking for? Thanks. People at Stack Overflow expect to receive some feedback when they try to help you.

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan Sorry i didn't reply.

Yes the solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderBerg, Can you please upvote and accept the solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a formula from `dplyr` package called `case_when`:

I just created a table based on your example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

A <- read_table("Weight  Days Chicken  Diet Group NewDiet
    42       0       1     1    G1     D1
    51       2       1     1    G1     D1  
    59       4       1     1    G1     D4     
    64       6       1     1    G1     D1     
    76       8       1     1    G1     D3     
    93      10       1     1    G1     D1     
    106     12       1     1    G1     D1     
    125     14       1     1    G1     D1     
    149     16       1     1    G1     D1     
    171     18       1     1    G1     D2 ")
```

If you want to create a new column in `A`:

```
A$Cost_Diet <-   case_when(A$NewDiet == "D1" ~ 2.2 * 10^(-5)/A$Weight,
                           A$NewDiet == "D2" ~ 2.8 * 10^(-5)/A$Weight,
                           A$NewDiet == "D3" ~ 3 * 10^(-5)/A$Weight,
                           A$NewDiet == "D4" ~ 3.2 * 10^(-5)/A$Weight)
```

Output:

```
> A
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   Weight  Days Chicken  Diet Group NewDiet   Cost_Diet
    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
 1     42     0       1     1 G1    D1      0.000000524
 2     51     2       1     1 G1    D1      0.000000431
 3     59     4       1     1 G1    D4      0.000000542
 4     64     6       1     1 G1    D1      0.000000344
 5     76     8       1     1 G1    D3      0.000000395
 6     93    10       1     1 G1    D1      0.000000237
 7    106    12       1     1 G1    D1      0.000000208
 8    125    14       1     1 G1    D1      0.000000176
 9    149    16       1     1 G1    D1      0.000000148
10    171    18       1     1 G1    D2      0.000000164
```

Or in a separate vector:

```
Cost_Diet <-   case_when(A$NewDiet == "D1" ~ 2.2 * 10^(-5)/A$Weight,
                           A$NewDiet == "D2" ~ 2.8 * 10^(-5)/A$Weight,
                           A$NewDiet == "D3" ~ 3 * 10^(-5)/A$Weight,
                           A$NewDiet == "D4" ~ 3.2 * 10^(-5)/A$Weight)
```

Output:

```
> Cost_Diet
 [1] 5.238095e-07 4.313725e-07 5.423729e-07 3.437500e-07 3.947368e-07 2.365591e-07 2.075472e-07 1.760000e-07
 [9] 1.476510e-07 1.637427e-07
```